# PHP: Generating SQL with an IF Statement difficulites

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, mysqli

I'm having a problem with using IF statements to 'choose' some MySQL code to run. Here's my code:

```
if ($numRows == 0 && count($terms) == 3) {
    $query2 .= " AND ( i.ING = '" . join("' OR i.ING = '", $terms) . "')". $queryType ." GROUP BY r.recipeID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) = 2)";
    $termCount = 2;

}

if ($numRows == 0 && $termCount == 2) {
    $query2 .= " AND ( i.ING = '" . join("' OR i.ING = '", $terms) . "')". $queryType ." GROUP BY r.recipeID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) = 1)";
```

This outputs:

```
    AND ( i.ING = 'wonton wrappers' OR i.ING = 'grape jelly' OR i.ING = 'lard') GROUP BY r.recipeID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) = 2) 
AND ( i.ING = 'wonton wrappers' OR i.ING = 'grape jelly' OR i.ING = 'lard') GROUP BY r.recipeID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) = 1)
```

However, i'm only wanting the 2nd line to be part of the query i'm going to use; but because the 1st if statement is always true aswell, it outputs that line too.

So the result I'd like to have based on the two statements is:

```
AND ( i.ING = 'wonton wrappers' OR i.ING = 'grape jelly' OR i.ING = 'lard') GROUP BY r.recipeID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) = 1)
```

It might be a case of i've been looking at it too long, and can't notice if it's some simplest thing i'm overlooking.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I noticed on your `if` statements, you are using `count($terms)` for the first, and `$termcCount` for the second, perhaps try changing them to the same?

Comment: It's quite obvious to get this output as you are assigning `$termCount = 2;` in your first condition & checking same in second condition which will be always true.

Comment: why does `term_count` is set to 2 ?

Comment: not an answer to your question but you could simplify the or parts in the sql to: `i.ING IN( 'wonton wrappers','grape jelly','lard')`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is the only code effected, I think your best bet is to simply replace `if ($numRows == 0 && $termCount == 2)` with `elseif ($numRows == 0 && $termCount == 2)`. (Basically, make it an else if clause to exclude the possibility of dupes)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest splitting the logic like this:

```
if ($numRows == 0) {
  $query2 .= " AND ( i.ING = '" . join("' OR i.ING = '", $terms) . "')$queryType GROUP BY r.recipeID";

  $query2 .= " HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING) = " . (count($terms) == 3 ? 2 : 1);
}
```

Taking advantage of the fact your branches are basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your first IF statement; if it is TRUE (and you enter that statement) you are setting $termCount to 2.  The second IF statement depends on $termCount == 2.  So right now if $numRows is 0 then both statements will always be true.  Find a different way to trigger the second IF statement; or simply remove $termCount = 2 from the first IF statement

Answer (score 0):

Make use of If else instead and form your statements such that the query only gets assigned to $query where it logically should.